# How to only show ACF field if another block is being used?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, block-editor

I'm developing a tab system on my site and I want to build the contents of the tabs using ACF blocks.

I have a "Tabs" block which handles the titles of the tabs. I have linked the index number of the tabs via JS and CSS to show and hide content on the page.

I'm currently using a ACF field to pick the tab the current block is shown in.
So there is a field "Choose the tab where this block will be shown in" with the choises 1 or 2 (being the index numbers of the tabs).

I am adding this field to each block, but I would like the field to be visible ONLY when I'm using the "Tabs" block on the same page.

The field "Choose the tab where this block will be shown in" is now shown on every page on my site, even when the "Tabs" block is not in use, and it can be confusing.

I tried hiding the field with CSS and then enqueuing a block-specific CSS file to show it but apparently the block-specific CSS file is loaded in admin even when the block is not in use so the CSS rule to show the field is always present in admin...

Is there any way to check if a specific block is being used on a page and then show a field in all of the blocks if that's the case?

Comment: Could you maybe add a screenshot or even better, a video, of the process, what is the current state and what is expected? I'm not really sure I understand the question